# Commenting overridden methods

Tags: .net, inheritance, comments

Do you comment overridden methods?

This is a general question, so forgive me if it isn't a 100% fit for Stackoverflow. I can't seem to find any information or examples on this on the internet apart from this similar SO question: [How to comment/document an override in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9915419/1061048)

Example:

```
/// <summary>
/// Updates this sample code.
/// </summary>
public virtual void Update()
{
    // do something
}

/// <summary>
/// Do you put a comment here?
/// </summary>
public override void Update()
{   
    base.Update()
    // do something else here
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should document what your method does and if the implementation has any peculiarity, then you should comment that. I personally find it that the more commenting the better - makes it easier for the next person to debug.